# Koin Android-KMM: I have nested scopes but injection is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, kotlin-multiplatform, koin

I am getting this error. I am using Koin for dependency injection.
I want my appointment repository to be alive as UserInfoContainer scope is alive.
No definition found for class:'com.flow.domain.repository.AppointmentsRepository'. Check your definitions!

UserInfoContainer class

```
class UserInfoContainer(private val encryptedLocalDatabase: EncryptedLocalDatabase) :
    KoinScopeComponent {
    override val scope: Scope get() = getOrCreateScope().value
var user: User?
    get() = encryptedLocalDatabase.user
    set(it) {
        if (it != encryptedLocalDatabase.user) {
            encryptedLocalDatabase.user = it
            scope.close()
        }
        }
}
```

Koin file

```
single { UserInfoContainer(encryptedLocalDatabase = get()) }

    scope<UserInfoContainer> {
        scoped<AppointmentsRepository> {
            AppointmentsRepositoryImplementation(
                apiService = get(),
                clinicId = get<UserInfoContainer>().user.let { it!!.clinicId }
            )
        }
    }
```

AppointmentsUseCase class

```
class AppointmentsUseCase : KoinComponent {
    private val appointmentsRepository: AppointmentsRepository by inject()

    suspend fun getAppointments(startDate: LocalDateTime, endDate: LocalDateTime): List<Appointment> =
        appointmentsRepository.getAppointments(startDate, endDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how I should inject my dependencies in the UseCase

```
class AppointmentsUseCase : KoinComponent {
    private val userInfoContainer: UserInfoContainer by inject()
    private val appointmentsRepository: AppointmentsRepository = userInfoContainer.scope.get()

    suspend fun getAppointments(
        startDate: LocalDateTime,
        endDate: LocalDateTime
    ): List<Appointment> =
        appointmentsRepository.getAppointments(startDate, endDate)
}
```